# How to get PropertyDescriptor for current property?

Tags: c#, .net, propertydescriptor

How can I get the `PropertyDescriptor` for the current property? For example:

```
[MyAttribute("SomeText")]
public string MyProperty
{
    get{....}
    set
    {
        // here I want to get PropertyDescriptor for this property.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could try this:

```
        public string Test
        {
            get
            {
                //Get properties for this
                System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptorCollection pdc = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetProperties( this );

                //Get property descriptor for current property
                System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor pd = pdc[ System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name ];
            }
        }
```

Comment: ou... nice, and I can write the System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptorCollection pdc = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetProperties( this ); in my constructor to use then only once... thanks!!

Answer (score 11):

Here's a re-usable conversion function for those who got to this post looking for a general function:

```cs
public static PropertyDescriptor GetPropertyDescriptor(PropertyInfo PropertyInfo)
{
    return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(PropertyInfo.DeclaringType).Item(PropertyInfo.Name);
}
```

and here's an extension method:

```cs
public static PropertyDescriptor PropertyDescriptor(this PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
{
  return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(propertyInfo.DeclaringType)[propertyInfo.Name];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I found that the following worked:

```
        //  get property descriptions
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties ( this );

        //  get specific descriptor
        PropertyDescriptor property = properties.Find ( PropertyName, false );
```

where `PropertyName` is a value passed into a method.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
this.GetType().GetProperty("MyProperty")
```

I think you're asking if you can do this without the string - i.e. some other token that represents 'this property'.  I don't think that exists.  But since you are writing this code anyway (?) what is the difficulty in just putting the name of the property in the code?

Comment: Is this case I'll get PropertyInfo... but I need TypeConverter, DisplayName from my Property..

Comment: also I can manually get all attributes and find typeConverter, but this is not good idea

Comment: also I can use TypeDescriptor.GetProperties( this ) and then run over all properties and find what I need... but maybe something buit-in was already implemented... and more quickly than that I wrote..

Comment: Your code isn't refactoring friendly. Use a lamda instead of a string.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - how could you do this using a lambda?  Could you post an example please?

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, you can now do this:

```cs
public static PropertyDescriptor? GetPropertyDescriptor(
    this object target, 
    [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = ""
) => TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(target.GetType())
        .Find(propertyName, ignoreCase: false)
```